# Automatically implementing an interface for wrapping an existing implementation

Tags: c#, interface, .net-4.0, mocking, implements

I have a class `A` that implements interface `IA`:

```
class A : IA
{
   f(){...}
}
```

I want to wrap `A` using a new class `WrapA` that will implement `IA` as well, with the intention of wrapping `A` by calling each one of its functions as a new task:

```
class WrapA : IA
{
  private A;
  f()
  {
    StartInNewTask(A.f());
  }
}
```

Of course this is very easy to do manually.

But I want an automatic mechanism for this wrapping, similar to the one mocks use to mock interfaces.

If it was done before I would love to see an example, or any idea on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best framework was Unity's interceptors.

Since I already used Unity Bootstrapper, it was quite easy to integrate.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx

The implementation (simplified, you will need to be careful with the return value):

```
public class RestPerformanceInterceptor : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    public bool WillExecute { get { return true; } }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(IA) };
    }

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var behaviorDelegate = getNext();

        StartInNewTask(behaviorDelegate.Invoke(input, getNext));

        return new Mock<IMethodReturn>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can use CodeDOM, a technology to dynamically create code. You construct your namespace/class in an object-oriented way. See [MSDN CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for detailed documentation.

In your case, you would need to read the methods you want to wrap via reflection, using the `Type.GetMethods`-Method. Thus, you access the target-methods using a `CodeMethodInvokeExpression`.
You need to have a reference to the wrapped object, which you can access using a `CodeVariableReferenceExpression`. With that, you can use the `CodeMethodInvokeExpression` to invoke the `Task.Run()`-Method (or whatever you use) and provide the Delegate and the reference to your target-object.

It is a bit of a complex topic, so you will need to read some documentation, but since it's a Microsoft technology it is very well documented feature. Once you have read it, it will be pretty easy to implement your wrapper.